# Counting and adding multiple variables from single cell in sheets

Tags: regex, variables, google-sheets, split, flatten

I have a sheets document that has cells that users input data into. They know to input the data in a certain format; a 'number' and a 'letter', followed by a space, a SKU number, and then a comma.
I'd like to have a formula that counts the amount of each 'letters' and then adds the 'numbers' for each letter.

There are only five 'letters' users can choose from; M, E, T, W, B.
The data they input isn't restricted to a set order, and there isn't a limit of how much they can input, as long as it follows the aforementioned syntax.

I attached a screenshot of an example of how this should look.
The yellow cell is the user inputted data, and the green cells is data created by formula.

[image: screenshot]

Or here's a link to a live version: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UPP3gfxV-7bq_cgPgpg-hDo7Zmmtn4-EFZ6PaNKgNdM/edit?usp=sharing)

I tried doing it with COUNTIF but that didn't work. I'm guessing it would be done with an array, but I don't know where to start. If I can see an example of something similar, I could probably do the rest.

Comment: Keep in mind that while your end goal and parameters are clear to you, they aren't clear to us from the outset. For instance, will you *always and only* want five returns per row? Or are there others that might turn up? If the latter, is there a finite set of possible "letters"? Will you always want the returns in the same order (i.e., M E T W B)? If so, will those always be entered in that order within the strings? As I say, there are a lot of unknowns yet from "out here."

Comment: I suggest you share a link to a sheet with enough realistic data to represent the full scope of possibilities, as well as manually entering (where you'd like a formula to output results what results) what the output for that data should be. Even 5 or 10 rows of data should be enough (if that covers the full range of possibilities that may arise in the raw data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A9, ",")), "\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.+?)\b(.*)", ROW(A2:A9)&"×$1$2×$1×$2")), "×"), 
 "select count(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col4 label count(Col2)''")))), 
 "offset 1", 0)*1&TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(SORT(FLATTEN(QUERY(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SPLIT(A2:A9, ",")), "\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(.+?)\b(.*)", ROW(A2:A9)&"×$1$2×$1×$2")), "×"), 
 "select count(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col4 limit 0 label count(Col2)''")))), 
 ".*sum", ))),,9^9)), "([^ ]+ [^ ]+) ", "$1×"), "×"), "(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$", "($1)"))
```

[image]

Comment: I copy pasted the answer

Comment: Works better now. Is there a way for it to work when there's only one piece of data?

Answer (score 1):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following solution:

`=ArrayFormula(FILTER( SPLIT("B E M T W", " ") & " (" & IFERROR(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1:A) & SPLIT("B E M T W", " "), QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IFERROR(REPT(ROW(A1:A) & REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A&",", "\d+,", ""), " ", 0, 1), "\D") & "~", 1*REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A&",", "\d+,", ""), " ", 0, 1), "\d+")))), "WHERE Col1 <>'' "), "~", 1, 1)), "Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) GROUP BY Col1"), 2, FALSE), 0)&")", A1:A<>""))`